# Gradle Upgrade Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, upgrade

I'm using Unity 2021.3.24f. My android project packages got upgraded and I did it. But it seems that they need upgraded version of the gradle as well. How can I do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcI7E.png)